# Svelte: passing styles and scripts to the href page with on:click event

Tags: svelte

Ok so basically i have a Main Page, that takes you to 2 pages, those 2 pages are the same, they only differ in the styling colors and a script operation, can anyone show me a logical procedure to merge the 2 pages and make the on:click event of the Main page differentiate the two.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share with use at least a REPL of what you are tring to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SvelteKit, a [`load` function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading) is provided in `<script context='module'>` which can get a `page` object with `page.params` containing the [dynamic part of page path](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing)

Say, `page.params.slug` for dynamic page `/pages/[slug].svelte`

Then the `load` function should return an object with `props` bringing the parameter. Say:

```
return {
  props: {
    pathInfo: page.params.slug
  }
}
```

In the dynamic page `[slug].svelte`, simply get the parameter like a normal prop via `export let pathInfo` in the `<script>` (note this is the normal script, not the `<script context='module'>` above)

With `<script>` knowing the path info, now you may import the same component via SvelteKit syntax `import SameComponent from '$lib/components/SameComponent'` , process the styling color/script operation, then pass them to the component

Below is the folder structure for my SvelteKit projects:

```
├── sveltekit-project/        // Root
|   ├── src/
|   |   ├── lib/
|   |   |   ├── components/
|   |   |   ... └── SameComponent.svelte
|   |   |   
|   |   ├── routes/
|   |   |   ├── main.svelte
|   |   |   ├── pages/
|   |   |   |   └── [slug].svelte
|   |   |   ...
|   |   ├── app.html
|   |   ...
```